# on POST what if entity exists - what is the correct response

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-post, http-status-codes

I have a RESTful API where one can `GET` Nodes and `Post` Nodes - basic stuff.

My "problem" is this:

When a user posts a new node, and that node already exists.
Should I return

1. `400 bad request`
2. `409 conflict`
3. `200 and the existing node`

Im leaning towards 200 and returning the existing node.
But the 409 and then letting the user get the correct node by themselves seems more "correct" if you will.

What is the "best practice" in this matter, for RESTful api's?

Answer (score 5):

The expected result of a POST is the creation of a *new* resource along with a 201 CREATED status code. Returning 200 OK is not appropriate because the request was not a success. Also see the RFC:

[200 OK](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response
>   is dependent on the method used in the request, for example:
>
> GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the
>   response;
>
> HEAD the entity-header fields corresponding to the requested resource
>   are sent in the response without any message-body;
>
> POST **an entity describing or containing the result of the action**;

---

Was there something wrong with the request? No. So 400 BAD REQUEST is not really appropriate either.

---

[409 CONFLICT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. **This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict** and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough

Is the user able to resolve the conflict? Yes, probably. If the conflict arises for example because a username is already taken, you can return that as error message to the user so that he can pick another username and thus resolving the conflict.

I would go with the 409.

Comment: Maybe a 302 or a 303 could suffice as well

Comment: @VisualBean 303 is specifically for redirecting web applications (websites). I suppose you *could* use it if you are making a website, but if you're not, it doesn't make alot of sense

Comment: Yeah you're right, so 409 - i think ill be pragmatic about it and return the original entity as well though, or should i jus stick with the program and let that be the users hassle?

Comment: @VisualBean I don't think it makes sense to return the conflicting entity. Just stating what the conflict is and how to resolve it should suffice. For example you wouldn't want user A to know user B's details

Comment: alhought that is already taken care of further down the "stack", I see your point.